# How to create a pagebreak using HTML Renderer with the latest beta version

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, html-renderer

When a page break is needed I have included

```
strPDF += "<div style='page-break-inside: auto;'></div>";
```

I also tried using

```
 strPDF += "<p style='page-break-inside: always;'></p>";
```

but this seems not to work.
Here I am using these

```
https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp/1.5.1-beta1
https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.Core/1.5.1-beta1
https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfSharp/1.51.5185-beta
```

Comment: [fisfro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10180737/fisfro) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66090476) saying "...there is only the possibility to create different pdf-pages as you can see https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer/issues/49#issuecomment-251351431"